# Is it possible to show variable shapes and lengths in vscode python debugger just like PyCharm does?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, vscode-debugger

In PyCharm, the lengths of lists and shapes of numpy arrays and pytorch tensors are shown in the debugger as in
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgRFi.png)

, which enables us to get these attributes without having to expand the variable, scroll down, and find the attributes one by one.
Is it possible to do this in VSCode?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with monkey-patching (use with caution as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching)), you can dynamically replace the *repr* of any class.
Add this to beginning of your debugged code, to get the Tensor *repr* you asked for. It is used by VSCode , but, may a

```
import torch
def custom_repr(self):
    return f'{{Tensor:{tuple(self.shape)}}} {original_repr(self)}'

original_repr = torch.Tensor.__repr__
torch.Tensor.__repr__ = custom_repr
```

You can do something similiar to the other classes you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In the watch view, you can write any expression. For example, instead of watching a list `arr`, you can watch `len(arr)`. If you had a NumPy array, you could do `arr.shape`. Anything works.

If you don't know what the watch view is, you can find it by typing "watch" into the command palette:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, this requires manually inputting the watch, what I want is to display them in the debugger automatically by maybe some configuration for the debugger.